# Filter related models by substring

Tags: django

Let's say I have the following models

```
class PizzaOrder(models.Model):
    order = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Topping(models.Model)
    topping = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and a `PizzaOrder` like this

```
order = PizzaOrder.objects.create(
    order='large pizza with onions, mushrooms and tuna'
)
```

Is it possible to perform a single query through django's ORM to get all the toppings used in this `PizzaOrder`?

This works but is expensive:

```
for topping in Topping.objects.all():
   if topping.topping in order.order:
      print("This order has a {} topping".format(topping.topping))
```

Comment: `PizzaOrder` doesn't use any of the `Topping`'s, there isn't any relationship defined there. So you don't need any queries, the answer is always None

Answer (score 0):

You could use django filters for this.
Since you don't have any relation with Topping in PizzaOrder table, you need to access all toppings to search in order table.

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q

toppings = Topping.objects.all()
topping_list = [topping.topping for topping in toppings]
query = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(order__icontains= item) for item in topping_list))
orders = PizzaOrder.objects.filter(query).distinct()
```

But i strongly recommend creating a relation between Topping and Order table as it will highly optimize your lookup query.